Как редактировать текст во время разметки в Label Studio? Или как это делается в любой другой системе разметки?
У меня есть текст в котором нужно выделить ключевые слова. Но этот текст может содержать ошибки и исправить их все заранее не всегда удается.
В Label Studio ни один из текстовых тегов (в которых можно делать разметку) не дает возможности поправить текст.
Как в целом происходит разметка текста в таких системах как LS если его невозможно исправить при необходимости во время разметки?
